# Change text language of InputFile in blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a blazor application that accept multi languages, I want to change the language of `InputFile` depends of `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`.

**Razor page**

```
string CultureLang = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name.Split('-') 
  [0].ToString();
 <InputFile class="form-control" OnChange="async (e) => await 
   LoadFiles(e)" multiple lang="@CultureLang"></InputFile>
```

I get the the right CultureInfo but UI of `InputFile` is still in English 
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the bootstrap and fontawesome to delete the default style of `InputFile`:

```
<label for="filePicker" class="label">
  <i class="fas fa-paperclip"></i>
  <span class="title">@Label</span>
  <InputFile id="filePicker" class="invisible" OnChange="async (e) => await LoadFiles(e)" multiple></InputFile>
</label>
```

**Css**

```
.label {
    width: 15rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
    border: 2px dashed;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em;
    transition: border 300ms ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
i{
    display: block;
    font-size: 42px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.title {
    transition: 200ms color;
}

.label:hover {
    border: 2px solid;
}
```

Note that `Label` is text that will be translated depends on `CurrentCulture`, I used here `IStringLocalizer` to get the right translation from the resource.